# Is it OK to merge another branch into mine and then merge both into master

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge, git-merge

Let's say I have three branches: `master`, `feature-A` and `feature-B`. I've added some commits to the `feature-A` branch and created a pull request that waits for code review.

Now I want to work on `feature-B`, but I'd like to use the code I've added in `feature-A`.

So, will it cause any problems if I:

- create branch `feature-A` from `master`
- add some commits to `feature-A`
- create branch `feature-B` from `master`
- merge `feature-A` into `feature-B`
- add some commits to `feature-B`
- merge `feature-A` into `master`
- merge `feature-B` into `master`

Will Git understand that some of the commits I'm merging from `feature-B` are already in `master`? Or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full disclosure: My current team has only been using git for 6 months, and I've only been using it in a team environment for about a year.  My use of git before that was always copying something out of ClearCase, dropping a `git init` on top of it, and tracking my offline changes...

That said, my team does what you mention fairly regularly, and git seems to handle it just fine.  What I will warn about is that if you're working on a team you really should have these kinds of conversations with them.  They may have decided to forbid this kind of thing in their workflow, and prefer instead that you rebase `feature-B` onto `feature-A` rather than add unnecessary merge commits (as just one example of an alternative way to handle this).

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

I would say that more natural solution would be to create branch b from branch a instead of master. However I believe both ways would work.

Comment: An example would be great